# Javascript constructor variable NAN inside function

Tags: javascript

I've tried to trace through all the possibilities of what's happening, but I'm learning Javascript so it has to be something I just don't know. The specific issue lies within the pongGame constructor/function; however, I have included my entire code just encase it is necessary. I would assume that, inside my gameLoop function which declared within the pongGame constructor, the variable pongGame.delta would be equal to 10; For, that is what I declared it to be. However, it is equal to NaN. What exactly is the issue that is happening here? Thanks :)

```
var keys = [false, false, false, false];
var cavnas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = cavnas.getContext("2d");
(function() {
  startUp();
})();

function startUp() {
  resize();
  window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
  var game = new pongGame();
  game.start();
}

function resize() {
  document.getElementById("canvas").width = window.innerWidth;
  document.getElementById("canvas").height = window.innerHeight;
}

function pongGame() {

  this.delta = 10;
  this.lastTime = 0;
  this.ball = new ball();
  this.start = function() {
    this.gameLoop();
  }
  this.update = function() {
    this.ball.update();
  }
  this.render = function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.ball.render();
  }

  var pongGame = this;
  this.gameLoop = function(timestamp) {
    console.log(pongGame.delta);      // 10
    pongGame.delta += timestamp - pongGame.lastTime;
    while (pongGame.delta > (1000 / 60)) {
      pongGame.update();
      pongGame.delta -= (1000/60);
    }
    pongGame.render();
    pongGame.lastTime = timestamp;
    requestAnimationFrame(pongGame.gameLoop);
  }

}

function paddle() {

}

function ball() {
  this.x = 1;
  this.y = 1;
  this.xspeed = 1;
  this.yspeed = 1;
  this.size = 10;
  this.update = function() {
    if (this.x == 0 || this.x == window.innerWidth - this.size) {
      this.xspeed = -this.xspeed;
    }
    if (this.y == 0 || this.y == window.innerHeight - this.size) {
      this.yspeed = -this.yspeed;
    }
    this.x += this.xspeed;
    this.y += this.yspeed;
  }
  this.render = function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.fill();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you call `gameLoop` you do not pass a timestamp so this expression `pongGame.delta += timestamp - pongGame.lastTime;` sets `delta` to NAN the first time its ran and then all subsequent runs (which have a timestamp) since its already NAN.
Maybe call it with 0 the first time

```
this.start = function() {
    this.gameLoop(0);
}
```

Comment: Gosh. All it takes is a second of a different pair of eyes. Thanks! I didn't realize this error because I didn't know javascript allows you to call functions w/o the correct matching parameters. Thanks!